# How can I use spotlight search to open a specific file path

Tags: finder, mojave, spotlight

Is there a way to do Command+Spacebar to open the spotlight search on macOS Mojave, and then give the path of a folder you want to open?

For example:

```
 "open ~/Documents/File"
```

or some equivalent.

If this isn't possible by default are there any extension to do this?  I was looking at Flashlight but was unsure if I needed it.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean "*give the path of a **file** you want to open*" not "*give the path of a **folder** you want to open*" in your first sentence?  Cmd+Space will open (and remember) a directory/folder such as `~/Documents/Whatever/` which will then open in Finder when you press enter...

Answer (score 1):

If you open Spotlight and type in the path of a specific folder and hit return that folder will open on your desktop in Finder. Put the full pathname but don't put open in the Spotlight search window.

Example: To open my python folder I type the following in the Spotlight window.
/User/myname/python . Now when I hit the return key the folder opens.

[image]

Comment: @user3439894 I got it right 2 out of three times!  Good for me!  lol

Comment: BTW You can type `~/python` too.